# ido mode opens wrong dired after writing file to a new directory

Tags: emacs

I have a file in `original_location/file_A`. I open it in emacs buffer, make some change, and rewrite it into another location: `new_location/file_A`.

Now, I want to open dired mode in the new location. So i type `C-x C-f`, but the dired still open the old location `original_location`.

How can I make ido to open the new location instead?

Comment: I just tried this with both my config and `emacs -Q` + `M-x ido-mode`.  I opened a file, did `C-x C-w`, saved to another directory, and then `C-x C-f`.  In both cases, `ido` started in the directory where I saved to.  There's almost surely something in your config (or a package you installed) that's doing this.

Comment: Do you see the same thing when starting Emacs with `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.